# Using Trace Listener redirects ALL Debug Output

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config, tracelistener

I followed this [Create a Logger using the Trace Listener in C#](http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/create-a-logger-using-the-trace-listener-in-csharp/)  article with the belief that only `Trace.WriteLine()` statements will be written in the `application.log` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="application.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

But to my dismay, all of my `Debug.WriteLine()` that used to go to the `Output` tab disappeared from that tab and instead they all now go to the trace file `application.log`.

Is there a way to direct **only** `Trace.WriteLine()` statements to that `application.log`?

If not, what is the simplest way to `WriteLine()` to a file of my own only what I choose to log to that file, not my entire debug session?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you've expected when `<remove name="Default" />` but removing that line from config will get you back output in the Output tab. You can see that [DefaultTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener.aspx) uses OutputDebugString method that allows VS to show logs in Output tab.

Traces send to all listeners and listener itself can do filtering.

If you want to do some more categorization of traces - see other classes in System.Diagnostic namespace like [TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) with samples in [How to - Trace Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
private static TraceSource mySource = new TraceSource("TraceSourceApp");
...
mySource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 1, "Error message.");
```

Comment: +1 for spotting that `<remove name="Default" />`. Commenting it out indeed restored the Output tab. But I still see all output in `application.log`. Is there a way I can direct to `application.log` **only** what I want to log there?

Comment: @ateiob The behavior is by design. Quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh3a61fw(v=vs.110).aspx) _"The Debug and Trace classes share the same Listeners collection. If you add a listener object to the collection in one of these classes, the other class uses the same listener."_